# Using React Hooks, why is the list of courses not rendering on the page even when I did setState?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, filtering

I'm learning to apply this multifilter function with React hooks and I am really lost. The idea is the user should be able to see all the list when the page is rendered and the user can filter by language and the date range... I have tried many different approaches and I really need help debugging this. It's either the list will show but the filter will not work or the filter will work but the list of courses will not show. I have been learning React Hooks and the use of useEffect but could not find a way to make this work.

```
  const index = ({ courseList }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [sortedCourses, setSortedCourses] = useState(courseList)
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date())
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };


  const handleLanguageClick = (event) => {
    setLanguage(event.target.value)
    if (event.target.value === 'all' || null) {
      setSortedCourses(courseList)
    } else {
      setSortedCourses(courseList.filter((course) => {
        return course.language === event.target.value
      }))
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    setSortedCourses(courseList)
  }, [courses])

  useEffect(()=>{
    filterDates()
  }, [startDate, endDate])

  const handleStartDateClick = (selectedDate) => {
    setStartDate(selectedDate)
    }
    
    const handleEndDateClick = (value) => {
      setEndDate(value)
      }
      
    const filterDates = () => {
        const sDateInput = moment(startDate).format('L')
        const eDateInput = moment(endDate).format('L')
       setSortedCourses(courseList.filter(course => {
          const sdate = course.startDate
          const edate = course.endDate
          return sdate >= sDateInput && edate <= eDateInput
      }))   
      }

  const handleClearButton = () => {
    setSortedCourses(courseList)
    setLanguage('')
    setStartDate(new Date())
    setEndDate(new Date())
  }

  return (
    <Container component='main'>
      <Grid container alignItems='center' justify='center'>
        <img className={classes.mainImage} alt="main image" src='/pic.jpg' />
      </Grid>
      <Grid className={classes.header} container alignItems='center' justify='center'>
        <Typography variant="h5" >ALL COURSES</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid className={classes.header} container alignItems='center' justify='center'>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" >Short Description here</Typography>
      </Grid>
      {/* FILTER */}
      <Grid container xs={12} alignItems='center' justify='flex-end'>
      <Grid item>
      <Typography>FILTER COURSES</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
      <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded
          })}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
      </IconButton>
     </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
      <Grid container justify='space-evenly' spacing={5} alignItems='center' >
        <StartDatePicker handleStartDateClick={handleStartDateClick} startDate={startDate}/>
        <EndDatePicker handleEndDateClick={handleEndDateClick} endDate={endDate} />
        <LanguageDropdown handleLanguageClick={handleLanguageClick} language={language} classes={classes} />
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClearButton}> Clear Filter </Button>
      </Grid>
      </Collapse>

      <br /><br />

      {/* COURSE CARDS */}
      <Grid container spacing={5} alignItems='flex-end'>   
          {sortedCourses.map((course) => (
          <Grid item key={course.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} >
            <CourseCard key={course.id} {...course} />
          </Grid>))}
      </Grid>
    </Container >
  )
}

index.propTypes = {
  courseList: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default index
```

Comment: `courses` in the dependency array for the first effect isn't defined anywhere in the snippet.

Comment: Also it seems your default state is to have the filter start and end date equal to the current date, so unless a course's start and end dates match exactly that it will be filtered out by default.